# expected ';' at end of declaration list objective c

Tags: objective-c

"error: expected ';' at end of declaration list" objective c
When I am trying to declare global variable

```
  @implementation CachingManager{
NSMutableArray*object = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create instance variables here but cannot initialize those instance variables here like you do. *They are all initialized to nil or zeroes. So compiler expect a semicolon when you are writing an equal sign.*

You can initialize them in init method or other method where your class initialization takes place in order to make them global variables. e.g.

**Interface block for instance variable inside .m file:**

```
@interface CachingManager ()
{
    // instance variables initialized to nil or zeroes
    NSMutableArray *object;   // global ivar
}
@end
```

---

**Implementation part same .m file:**

```
@implementation CachingManager

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    object = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   // initialization takes place
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to implement global variables, and to manage their lifetime (i.e. that they are initialised) and even to provide global methods is to implement a class exposing those variables/methods and to use the singleton pattern:

**yourFile.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalVars : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *_truckBoxes;
    NSMutableArray *_farmerlist;
    NSString *_farmerCardNumber;
    NSString *_fName;
}

+ (GlobalVars *)sharedInstance;

@property(strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableArray *truckBoxes;
@property(strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableArray *farmerList;
@property(strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *farmerCardNumber;
@property(strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *fName;

@end
```

**yourFile.m:**

```
#import "GlobalVars.h"

@implementation GlobalVars

@synthesize truckBoxes = _truckBoxes;
@synthesize farmerList = _farmerList;
@synthesize frameCardNumber = _frameCardNumber;
@synthesize fName = _fName;

+ (GlobalVars *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static GlobalVars *instance = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[GlobalVars alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _truckBoxes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _farmerlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // Note these aren't allocated as [[NSString alloc] init] doesn't provide a useful object
        _farmerCardNumber = nil;
        _fName = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

You can then use these global variables like this, for example:

```
GlobalVars *globals = [GlobalVars sharedInstance];
globals.fName = @"HelloWorld.txt";
[globals.farmerList addObject:@"Old Macdonald"];
[self processList:[globals farmerList]];
```

However, please consider:

You don't need to use global variables like this; you should be able to create a model object which is created as necessary and reference to it passed to the views. This is MVC.
You also posted a stack trace of an unrelated issue which is extremely common with Objective-C; only you can fix this error, once you realise what it is.

Answer (score 1):

That sin't a global variable.  That would be an instance variable and that particular syntax wasn't commonly used after 2005 (really, it wasn't terribly common after the mid 90s).

If you want a global variable, do:

```
 NSMutableArray *myGlobal;
```

Somewhere at the top level -- at the same level with the `@implementation` -- of your source.

You'll have to initialize the global variable elsewhere, though.  Typically, in the +initialize or +load method of the class.

Comment: my class is  NSObject I need to initialise it one time before use it ,I which method I can do this ?